# How to map list of children object as list of String with MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

My parent class is:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    Long id;

    String username;

    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

My child class is:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Role {

    Long id;
    
    String name;

}
```

I would like to map with MapStruct (last version) this object structure to the following:

```java
public class UserDto {

    Long id;

    String username;

    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

I have a simple mapper already working but I was unable (after hours of Google search and test) to determine the good way to achieve the conversion of .roles from `Set<Role>` to `Set<String>`:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDto map(User user);

//  List<String> map(List<Role> roles);
}
```

Comment: Does adding `default String map(Role role) { return role.getName(); }` work? MapStruct should then use that to map each role to a string when it creates its own `List<Role>` to `List<String>` conversion method which is then used inside the `map(User)` method.

Comment: Your answer solve my problem perfectly. Thank you!

The piece of MapStruct documentation related is: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Rob Spoor comment, MapStruct allow default method implementation is the interface for more-than-declarative mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    UserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    UserDto map(User user);

    Set<String> map(Set<Role> roles);

    default String map(Role role) { return role.getName(); }

}
```

Ref: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods